# Identify consumer of Azure Service Bus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm taking over responsibility for an Azure Service Bus deployment. Documentation is incomplete in that there are undocumented Queues and Topic Subscriptions present.

What information can Azure provide me about the function that is consuming messages sent to a queue/topic subscription? I'd like ultimately to be able to locate the source code which is processing the messages.

e.g. a class library name, class name or even just a namespace of the function that receives the messages. Something. Anything.

Or am I asking the wrong question?

Comment: If the producing/consuming applications have an Application Insights integration the [Application Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net) might reveal this information

Comment: Looks like some functions are using Insights, and some not.

Comment: For the functions that don't have AppInsights integration it would be difficult to determine. Alternatively, scanning the code in the repositories to identify entities or, other sources (such as build server) where configuration changes could be applied.

Comment: @SeanFeldman yep - that's proving to be less successful than you'd expect/hope. I suspect some of this was crafted manually during the "learning" phase of ASB and deployment and is actually  superseded or redundant, but I'm not switching anything off until I've exhausted all avenues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Seems like an oversight on Azure that all information about Service Bus ends at the definition of the "inbox" and offers nothing about the functions that deal with received messages.

Problem is, the whole idea of using a Service Bus is to decouple (parts of) applications, so the sender does not have a tight relationship with the receiver of the message. From your story it seems your consumers are probably Azure Functions but in other situations receiver might be running on-premises or in an other cloud environment like AWS or Google Cloud. The Azure Service Bus does simply not know what kind of hosting environment is consuming the messages. Tools like Application Insights can generate this kind of information but only if enabled on the consuming side.

> What information can Azure provide me about the function that is consuming messages sent to a queue/topic subscription? I'd like ultimately to be able to locate the source code which is processing the messages.
>
> e.g. a class library name, class name or even just a namespace of the function that receives the messages. Something. Anything.

If the producing/consuming applications have an Application Insights integration the [Application Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net) might reveal this information.

Enabling Azure Functions to consume Service Bus messages is all based on configuration so you could scan your code repositories based topic names but there are plenty of other locations where this configuration can be stored like [Azure Function Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings), Azure Key Vault, Azure App Configuration etc.

> Even a statement "There are no consumers on this queue/subscription" would be a help.

The closest you can get is see whether there are [active messages waiting to be delivered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-counters#using-azure-portal):

[image]

If there is no (active) consuming subscription while messages are pushed I would expect an increasing value of the Active Message Count metric. But do mind the Message Time to Live for the specific topic.

> Or am I asking the wrong question?

It is a valid question and I definitely feel your pain but there is no satisfying answer to your question. For loosly coupled systems you need documentation, distributed tracing and possibly infrastructure as code to tackle issues like this.

**Getting a list of Azure Functions and their bindings**

In your comments you mention that it would help to get a list of functions and their bindings. I do know how to do that using the [management SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/doc/dev/mgmt_quickstart.md):

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;

internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
        {
            ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
            ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true
        }));

        var azureFunctions = new List<SiteFunctionResource>();

        foreach (var subscription in client.GetSubscriptions())
        {
            var resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
            await foreach (var resourceGroup in resourceGroups.GetAllAsync())
            {
                var websites = resourceGroup.GetWebSites();
                azureFunctions.AddRange(
                    websites
                        .Where(ws => ws.Data.Kind.Contains("functionapp", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        .SelectMany(ws => ws.GetSiteFunctions().ToList())
                    );
            }
        }

        foreach (var azureFunction in azureFunctions)
        {
            var bindings = azureFunction.Data.Config.ToObjectFromJson<Config>().bindings;
            Console.WriteLine(azureFunction.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("bindings:");
            foreach (var binding in bindings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{binding.name}: {binding.type}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Binding
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string route { get; set; }
        public List<string> methods { get; set; }
        public string authLevel { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Config
    {
        public List<Binding> bindings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It needs the following NuGet packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.7.0-beta.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.AppService" Version="1.0.0-beta.3" />
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 
[Quote]"whole idea of using a Service Bus is to decouple (parts of) applications"
Agree, but imagine where someone deploys a consumer to the wrong topic subscription by mistake, and all messages it processes fail. It could cause the Topic to fill, and surely I can't have no way to find that consumer?

Comment: @NeilMoss I've update my answer to help you get a list of functions and their bindings.

Comment: *but imagine where someone deploys a consumer to the wrong topic subscription by mistake, and all messages it processes fail. It could cause the Topic to fill, and surely I can't have no way to find that consumer?* Thing is, an SB subscriber **pulls** messages to process so the ASB does not (need to) know anything about the consumers. Compare that with Azure Event Grid where events are **pushed** to subscribers so the destination needs to be known upfront, like an azure function for example. In the case of Event Grid getting all known subscribers is easy to do because of the push based nature.

Comment: @NeilMoss Also, you could try to enable application insights for the functions that do not have it enabled using [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#enable-application-insights-integration) and see whether the application map builds a nice overview of all the connected functions.