# Is there a way to get logs from all recently-run Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to get the name, type, associated resource group, trigger time, trigger type, and trigger source for all Azure Functions within a subscription? We have set up a number of Azure Functions over time but they are not cleanly organized or properly documented, so we only know that we have a lot of Functions executing but we don't know when they're scheduled to execute, what triggers their execution, etc. Having this information would help us better balance jobs and more effectively plan how to add and schedule other automated tasks.

Comment: Each of the function app can be linked to an _Application Insights_ resource, then from App Insights you can know the execution details, duration, execution result of the function executions.

Comment: I don't think there is an out-of-the box solution. I know that https://www.serverless360.com/ is able to give a holistic view of all your resources, including azure functions. Per function you can see the type of trigger and some parts of the configuration (like schedule for time based triggers)

Comment: I once created a small app that shows at least the function, type of trigger and name of trigger. It can be easily extended to show the schedule for timer triggers and the route and methods of http triggered functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73291141/identify-consumer-of-azure-service-bus-queue/73372592#73372592

Comment: Thanks so much Anand and Peter for your responses! I will check out the link you shared Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get to know the trigger, which is triggering at which time, by enabling application insights while creating your function app like below:

[image]

Then when you run the trigger, you can check in logs of appinsights of function app which trigger is running like below.

You can use kusto query to get the details of functions running:

[image]

Another query:

[image]

Over here you will get to know about the logs of function app:

[image]